# Bootstrap Togglable Tab page boundary detection

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a bootstrap based UI for a site which would have multiple number of tabs on the page.

I would have a button which would create a new tab on the fly.

```
<ul id="tabsList" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<br />
<input type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-info" id="btnAddTab" value="click to add tab"></input>

i = 1;
$("#btnAddTab").on("click", function () {
    $("#tabsList").append("<li><a href='#'>Tab " + i + "</a></li>");
    i++;
 });
```

Now what I've observed is that when the width of the page is filled with tabs, I see that the tabs are being created in new row. This is what I am trying to avoid.

I've looked around and I've seen that I could use multilevel menus in tabs, So I thought what if I could create x amount of tabs, and at the end of the page, change it to dropdown and continue adding tabs to the dropdown menu.

I have created an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/fatgamer85/5pFv3/

I don't actually know how to figure out when the page ends when I am adding the tab. So, can anyone assist me with the logic of finding out how to detect that the tabs are being pushed to edge?

once I've figured it out, I could create an inner list and keep on adding my items to that list.

**UPDATE:
I have fixed this by manually counting the width of the container and restricting the generation of more tabs in the main tab and moving newly generated tabs to "More" tab:
Here is the final solution: https://jsfiddle.net/LE6Ty/6/** *(Last Updated 01/12/2017)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to change a tab-nav to a dropdown list based navigation on click.

```
function changeToDropdown(){
    $("#tabsList").removeClass("nav");  //Remove tab classes on the list.
    $("#tabsList").removeClass("nav-tabs"); // ^
    $("#tabsList").addClass("dropdown-menu"); //Add dropdown-menu classes to the list.
    $("#tabsList").attr("role","menu"); //Add menu role to the list.  
    $("#futureDropdown").addClass("dropdown");  //Adds dropdown class to the surrounding div.
    $("#dropdownButton").show();  // Show the "dropdown" button.
}
```

I made these two changes to the html to make it work.

1. Add an `<a>` tag like the one below. Either hide it with JQuery or css.

   `<a id="dropdownButton" class="btn btn-large btn-bloc dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" style="display:none;">DropDown</a>`
2. Surround the  tag and tabs list with the a `<div>` with an id of #futureDropdown

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Here we go: http://jsfiddle.net/3boll/5pFv3/6/

```
i = 1;
$("#btnAddTab").on("click", function () {
    if(i<5){
        // first 4 tabs
        $("#tabsList").append("<li><a href='#'>Tab " + i + "</a></li>");
        i++;
        return;
    }
    if(i===5){
        // The dropdown tab ( id='dd')
        $("#tabsList").append("<li class='dropdown'><a class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'>More <b class='caret'></b></a><ul class='dropdown-menu' id='dd'></ul></li>"); 
        $("#dd").append("<li><a href='#'>Tab " + i + "</a></li>");
        i++;
        return;
    }
    if(i>5){
        // Tabs 6 to ...
        $("#dd").append("<li><a href='#'>Tab " + i + "</a></li>");
        i++;
        return;
    }
});
```

---

```
var totalWidth = 0;
var divWidth = $("#tabsList").width();

$("#btnAddTab").on("click", function () {
    $("#tabsList li").each(function () {
        totalWidth += $(this).width();

    });
    //alert(totalWidth);
    //alert(divWidth);

    if (totalWidth < divWidth) {
        $("#tabsList").append("<li><a href='#'>Tab</a></li>");
    }

    if (totalWidth > divWidth) {
        if ($("#tabsList li.dropdown").length === 0) {
            $("#tabsList").append("<li class='dropdown'><a class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'>More <b class='caret'></b></a><ul class='dropdown-menu' id='dropdownList'><li><a href='#'>New Tab</a></li></ul></li>");
        } else {
            $("#dropdownList").append("<li><a href='#'>New Tab</a></li>");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi 3Boll, This is exactly what I'm trying to do. But I've noticed in your code that you are simply adding 4 tabs and converting the rest to drop-down via a counter.

I want that functionality to be done automatically without any counters depending on the width of the div the tabs are in.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this plugin that may help you solve this problem a little better:
http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-tabdrop/

Very useful script when your tabs do not fit in a single row. This script takes the not fitting tabs and makes a new drop-down tab. In the drop-down there are all the tabs that do not fit.

Works only with horizontal tabs and pills
custom text for the drop-down tab
works with responsive design

Comment: Hi Nekreerv, that's a really cool plugin.

I have already solved this issue way back in June!. My solution would also work with tabs and pills ^_^